# Pycharm -- import function doesn't find the function doesn't recognize imported modules

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

If in the main python script numpy and pandas are imported

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
```

and a function is then imported from funcs.py that uses pandas

```
import funcs.py  as fp
report = fp.generate_report(arguments)
```

results in an error --> NameError: name pd is not defined when function is called

Do I have to import pandas within every function that uses it in pycharm?

Comment: You will need to import pandas in the funcs.py file

Comment: Thanks -- that was the only solution that I could come up with too.